# javascript is not executing inserted in inner HTML

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to get the response from another page for example its name is `ajaxresponse.php` through ajax request and I also want to perform some actions done by java script on that `ajaxresponse.php` page but the js code is not working. I am getting the response from that page but the js code for that page is not working. I want to only know why ajax code on mie second page is not working?

```
function ajaxinput(tinnerid)
{
    var xmllhttp;
       if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
       else
        {
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
           {
            document.getElementById("articledive").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
           }
        }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxresponse.php?q="+tinnerid,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Here is the php code for first page

```
<?php
 $con1=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","root","databasetry");
 $result=mysqli_query($con1,"select title,articleid  from article");
 $tinnerid=0;
 $articledivid=0;
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
     $tinnerid=$row['articleid'];
     echo "<div class='tinner' id='$tinnerid' onclick='ajaxinput($tinnerid)'    style='cursor:pointer;'>";
     echo"<span class='fontdiv'>";
     echo $row['title']."<br>";
     echo "</span>";
     echo"</div>";
     $tinnerid++;
     $articledivid++;
    }
 mysqli_close($con1);
?>
```

Here is the js code for second page

```
function run()
{
 alert("example");
}
```

Here is the php code of second page

```
 <?php
  $id=$_GET['q'];
  $result=mysqli_query($con1,"select user.username,article.articleid,article.title,article.artiletext from article inner join user on article.user_id=user.user_id where article.articleid=$id");
 $divid=0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {   
      $id=0; 
      echo"<div class='inner' id=$divid >";
      $id=$row['articleid'];
      echo "<font class='ftitle'>"."Title : "."<a href='#'onclick='ajaxinput($id)'>".$row['title']."</a>"."</font>"."<br>"."<font class='ftext'>".$row['artiletext']."</font>"."<br>"."<font class='flast'>"."Posted By : ".$row['username']."</br>"."</font>"."<br>"."<br>";    
      echo "<button type='button' onclick='con($id)'  class='button'><font size='1'>Delete</font></button>";
      echo"</div>";
      $divid++;
      echo"<script>run()</script>";   
      }
  mysqli_close($con1);
 ?>
```

Comment: JavaScript does not get executed when inserted by innerHTML. Now to find a dupe.

Comment: whats the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript inserted as innerHTML at runtime won't be executed. A possible solution is to remove the script tag from the second page return, and call the method `run()` on the first page, after the ajax callback. Like this:

```
function ajaxinput(tinnerid)
{
   var xmllhttp;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
   else
    {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
       {
        document.getElementById("articledive").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

        /* CALL IT HERE AFTER INSERT */
        run();
       }
    }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxresponse.php?q="+tinnerid,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```